# Sandbox rendering differently than localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, deployment

This may be a shot in the dark but I have some html on localhost like this:

```
<div>
 <p>Go to: <a href="www.foobar.com">here</a></p>
</div>
```

When rendered, it's showing as "Go to: here" with here as a link (as expected).

However, when deployed to sandbox, the html is rendered as "Go to:here" (no space).

I can't for the life of me figure out why. The code goes through minification but is there anything else that may be causing this issue?

Any help/suggestions are appreciated thanks!

Comment: Are you compressing your HTML. That has a tendency to remove not required whitespaces.

Comment: don't know why but you could probably add &nbsp; instead of the space to fix it

Comment: Instead of leaving the link blank you may want to use # as a placeholder and see if that changes things. If you're using a builder of any kind it might be minifying/removing empty links.

Comment: replace the blank space with `&nbsp;` and change the attribute to `href="#"`

Comment: sorry i'm actually hrefing (just edited the post) to something but i'll put in &nbsp for the space and see if that fixes it

Comment: &nbsp fixed it guys thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using `&nbsp;` you can force a space, not the most elegant way, but a quick fix. Have you checked the minified Version for the missing " "?

Comment: adding &nbsp; seems to have done the trick. What I'm wondering though is this something I always have to do when needing a space between text and an <a> now in order for it to render correctly?

Comment: @ProgrammingGodJK maybe minifying with other tool, I mean it seems like the problem might be with the tool and not something you can do much about it (except work arounds like `&nbsp;`). I wouldn't worry too much